# How do I access the String value inside a for loop?

Tags: java

Here I am not able to access the value of the `name` outside of the string even if I use other string the value is not initializing.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\n\tWelcome to the Store");
    System.out.print("\nPls enter the number of items you want to bill ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    String name;
    for(int i = 1;i<=100;i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the item no "+i+" ");
        name = sc.next();
        if (i == n) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();   
    for(int m=1;m<=n;m++) {
        //System.out.println(name);        
    }    
}
```

Comment: The code is incomplete. Where is `name` declared?  The answer to that determines where it can be accessed.

Comment: like ok im gonna upload whole code...is it okk?

Comment: Well, preferably just as post as much as is needed to answer the question!

Comment: bro its my first time idk much and basically it's ok  im just practicing

Comment: OK, I;m just saying if you can identify something other than 'all the code' then that helps readers here.

Comment: sorry i didnt get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `name` to be an array since it should contain several values.

```
String[] names = new String[n];
```

I also think you should use a `while` loop instead. Something like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\n\tWelcome to the Store");
System.out.print("\nPls enter the number of items you want to bill ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
String[] names = new String[n];
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the item no " + i + " ");
    names[i] = sc.next();
    i++;
}
System.out.println();
for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
    System.out.println(names[m]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But I hope this will fix it. Be sure to initialize variable n with a value that you want.

```
 import java.util.*;
 
 class example{
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
 
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     String[] name = new String[100];
     int n=3; // make sure to change this one
     
     for(int i = 1;i<=3;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the item no "+i+" ");
            name[i] = sc.next();
     }
     for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
            System.out.print(name[i]+"\n");
    }

}
}
```